# What is the correct way in Rollup.js to add a banner to minified files?

Tags: rollup

What is the correct way to add a banner to a minified js file created with Rollup.js?

So far I have tried the builtin `output.banner` option, but this gets removed by the minifier.

```js
// rollup.config.js
export default {
  ...,
  output: {
    ...,
    banner: BANNER,
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  plugins: {
    terser(),
  }
}
```

I have also tried using `rollup-plugin-banner`.

```js
{
  ...,
  output: [{ 
    ...,
    sourcemap: true,
  }],
  plugins: [
    terser(),
    banner(BANNER),
  ],
},
```

This kind of works, but throws the following error message for each file processed by rollup.

```
(!) Broken sourcemap
https://rollupjs.org/troubleshooting/#warning-sourcemap-is-likely-to-be-incorrect
Plugins that transform code (such as "banner") should generate accompanying sourcemaps.
```

How do I get this to work without the error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually because of `terser`:

> `comments` (default `"some"`) -- by default it keeps JSDoc-style comments that contain "@license", "@copyright", "@preserve" or start with `!`, pass `true` or `"all"` to preserve all comments, `false` to omit comments in the output, a regular expression string (e.g. `/^!/`) or a function.

You can either change your banner text a bit (based on the above rules) so terser won't remove it or use terser's `preamble` option (instead of rollup's `output.banner`):

```
plugins: [
    // ...
    terser({
        format: {
            preamble: '// Copyright example ...'
        }
    })
    // ...
]
```